# IfWinExist, WinActivate are not detecting java.exe windows

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to close a particular java.exe window that I gave a custom title when I launched it from cmd. Here's what it looks like in windowSpy.ahk:

```
CloseMe
ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
ahk_exe java.exe
ahk_pid xx_Changes_Every_Time_xx
```

Here's my code:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#WinActivateForce
DetectHiddenWindows, On

IfWinExist, "ahk_exe java.exe"
  MsgBox, Exists
Else
  MsgBox, Does Not Exist
```

And I keep getting "Does Not Exist" despite my many efforts:

1. Used the title (CloseMe), class (ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass) and exe (ahk_exe java.exe)
2. `WinActivate, "CloseMe"` (and the rest)
3. `WinClose, "CloseMe"`
4. `WinGet, w_list, List, "Close"`

It seems like Window Spy has no problem telling me the aspects of this window, but AHK will not allow me to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to have quotes on the title, unless you're concatenating it.

```
WinActivate, CloseMe
WinClose, CloseMe
```

Comment: You don't need quotes at all, this would work: `WinClose, CloseMe ahk_exe java.exe`